# TCP Recv using select() returning 1 byte reads

Tags: c++, sockets, select, recv

In my code below, I am doing a send(23 bytes) and then in an infinite while loop doing a recv whenever data is ready(as per the return from the select call). The problem is that I always seem to end up getting 1 byte reads from the recv(). I understand that the TCP is stream oriented, and there is no guarantee of what size I'll get back, but if I enable the code I've disabled below(i.e. do a recv in a while loop infitiely) - I always seem to read 29 bytes(what I expect). However, if I use the select function call, recv only reads 1 byte in every iteration. It keeps doing this forever(likely when its finished reading all the data).

```
 int rc = 0, numBytes=0 ; 
 char reply[256] ; 

 // Send a ping
 char PingPacket[23] ; 

 PreparePingPacket(PingPacket) ; 
 numBytes = send(m_sockfd,PingPacket,23,0); 

/*----- COMMENTED OUT
while(1){
  rc = recv(m_sockfd, reply, 256, 0) ;
  if(rc == -1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error on Sending Ping .. \n") ;   
    return ; 
  }else{
    ParsePacket(reply, rc) ; 
  }
}
*/ END OF COMMENTED PART

// Now wait for all types of pongs to come back
fd_set rfs ; 
while(1)
{
  memset(reply,'\0',256) ; 

FD_ZERO(&rfs) ;

FD_SET(m_sockfd,&rfs) ; 

// Wait for ever .. 
if((rc = select(m_sockfd+1, &rfs, NULL, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Select Error after connection .. \n") ; 
  close(m_sockfd) ; 
  return ;
}

if(FD_ISSET(m_sockfd, &rfs))
{
  cout << "Read. for reading" << endl ; 
  int rc = 0 ; 
  if((rc = recv(m_sockfd, reply, sizeof(reply), 0)) == -1)
  {
    cout << "Could not read anything .... " << endl ;   
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: %d\n",errno) ; 
    return ; 
  }
  else if(rc == 0)
  {
    cout << "The other side closed the connection. \n" << endl ; 
  }

}

.....
```

Any ideas on why this is happening ?

Comment: To start with, stop mixing C-style `stdio` functions like `fprintf` and C++ stream output. Use one or the other. If you want to print to "standard error" then use `std::cerr`.

Comment: As for your problem, using `select` will only guarantee that you can call e.g. `recv` without it blocking, there is no guarantee about the number of bytes available. You should also remember that TCP doesn't guarantee that you will be able to get all data in a single `recv` call, you might have to call it multiple times to get all data, which of course may be problematic if the socket is blocking.

Comment: Also, could you please show the declaration of `reply`?

Comment: added the declaration of reply.

Comment: You could use non-blocking sockets and read in a loop until you get the whole packet. Other than that there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Your code looks perfectly good to me. If that's TCP/IP, it is probably worth submitting a bug report to the maintainer of your network stack, as it is broken. Yes, `recv` is in principle allowed to return 1 byte at a time, but this does not mean it is legitimate here. IPv4 mandates a minimum MTU of 576 and IPv6 mandates a minimum MTU of 1280, so there is no way you could send a single message of 29 bytes so it doesn't fit in a single datagram and arrives in one unit. When a unit of 29 bytes is in the receive buffer, and the application requests at least that, then 29 bytes should be received.

Comment: The "`recv`may return less than what you ask for" clause in the API contract is meant to account for the fact that TCP abstracts the underlying packet layer, so when you send large amounts of data, you have no knowledge (or control) about whether it will be broken up in several datagrams and when each of them arrives. Thus, less data than you currently expect may be available at a time on the "stream". It does however _not_ mean that `recv` is generally supposed to return less than what you ask, even if the data is available. To all appearances, this is what happens here, so it's "broken".

Comment: Whee is the *evidence?* Where are you printing out 'rc' if it isn't zero or -1?

Comment: @Damon That is exactly what it means. There is no breakage here, because there is no guarantee to the contrary. And MTU alone is not a sufficient determinant.

Comment: @EjP: Of course there is breakage. The MTU is required to be a certain minimum, and the receive buffer is required to be able to receive at least one maximum-sized datagram. A datagram is either completely accepted (checksum ok) it's not, not at all. Thus, there is no way short of "not working" that sending a single less-than-MTU message using a single call to `send` arrives in any other way (and the entire data becomes available) than in one piece. `recv` by definition shall return data (up to the supplied buffer length) _as it becomes available_, not some time later, one byte at a time.

Comment: If you want a more computer-related example, consider the `sched_yield` function. According to POSIX, the function sets `errno` if it fails. Consequentially, if you use `sched_yield` in a program and you do not verify the return code (and possibly `errno`), I insist that your program is not correctly checking error conditions. Now tell me, _with no error codes defined_ in the standard, which error codes do you check for, and _exactly what_ action would you take after discovering that yielding has failed? It's nonsensical to be an API-lawyer.

Comment: I tried to run the same code over on my university's servers, but had the exact same issue there as well.

Comment: @Damon These are not datagrams, this is TCP. TCP is entitled to *send* one byte at a time if it likes. Criminal behaviour and thread yields are irrelevant to the behaviour of TCP. Please stop this nonsense.

Comment: @EJP: No, that's simply not true. That is an entirely ridiculous interpretation of the "segment may consist of the complete or partial contents of one or several sends" sentence. An implementation that -- for no good reason -- uses less than 0.1% of the underlying network layer's MTU and adds a 12,400% protocol overhead (twelve thousand percent, say that three times in a row!) is _broken_ no matter how much you discuss, and no matter whenter it's generally allowable to send less than one send's full contents.

Answer (score 0):

in the commented out section you have

```
rc = recv(m_sockfd, reply, 256, 0) ;
```

and in the select you have

```
if((rc = recv(m_sockfd, reply, sizeof(reply), 0)) == -1)
```

no sure if the definition of replay is the same function as the recv or you passed it as a parameter. Try to print the sizeof(replay) before the call to see that is actually 256.

Comment: Verified by printing it's 256. Still the same result.

Answer (score -2):

Once **select()** informs you about data available, you have to call **accept()** and then determine a new socket to actually read that data.

So, you can think about **select()** as an "ear socket". Once the "ear" hears something, it creates another socket dedicated to send-receive TCP stream between you and "heared" remote party. Once remote party is no longer available, you have to close that socket. Same time, "ear" socket persists until you're interested in serving incoming connection requests.

Comment: That's only correct if you're calling `select` on a socket that has been set to `listen`. That does not seem to be the case here.